# how to using mount function in code to mount ntfs-3g?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have question about the mount function , I want to mount a ntfs disk , and I had ntfs-3g driver ready, I could mount this disk using ntfs-3g command or mount command in shell, but when I try using
 `mount("/dev/sda1", "/mnt/sda1","ntfs-3g",MS_MGC_VAL,NULL);`
it always fails.

What can I do? I don't wanna using "System()" because in my system it always return -1(I don't why, stupid busybox ash?), I need the status to identify it mount successful or not.

Please help , thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: To start with, you should check `errno` after `mount` fails, so you know _why_ it fails. Use e.g. `perror` or `strerror` to print a short description of the error.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking into this very issue for a couple of hours now, and I believe that what's going on is a mis-understanding of how these things work.

1. The mount program (/bin/mount on my Centos 6.5 system) is NOT a simple wrapper around the mount system call. In fact, it's quite intelligent in figuring out what it's dealing with, and what to try to get that thing mounted.
2. The mount system call ONLY works will filesystem drivers that are kernel modules. Things you'd find in /etc/filesystems or /proc/filesystems.

ntfs-3g is a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) driver. The only proper way to mount a FUSE filesystem is to use the appropriate mount program. (ntfs-3g or /sbin/mount.ntfs on my system). That's because in addition to kernel resources being needed, a user-space program has to be run. It's the userspace program that knows how to interpret the disk format, NOT the kernel end of things.

The normal system mount program figures out that it has to call something else to make the mount happen, and automatically deduces that it needs /sbin/mount.ntfs and calls it for you. The underlying mount system call has no such functionality. It just knows that it can't mount the given filesystem and fails.

So, you have two choices:

1. Fix whatever is wrong with the mount command on your system. You might want to investigate whether you've got an actual 'mount' binary or not. If you do, calling it directly might help.
2. If you KNOW the thing is going to be ntfs formatted, and you DON'T have a real mount program, then you might want to try calling ntfs-3g directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these solutions:

1. Verify if you have the right permissions to mount and unmount the filesystem.
2. `int mount(const char *source, const char *target, const char *filesystemtype,`                `unsigned long mountflags, const void *data);`

   The values for the `filesystemtype` argument  supported  by  the  kernel  are
   listed  in  `/proc/filesystems`. Further types becomes  visible  when  the
   appropriate modules are loaded. Check if `ntfs-3g` is listed there.
3. Check the `errno` value set by the mount system call and fix the problem based on the errno description. Source: `man -s 2 mount`

   Its very easy. Just add `#include "errno.h"` in your source code. Then you could verify from the man page of mount, what is the error mount is getting into. Here is a sample code to get you started:

> ```
> int retval = mount();//your system call
> if( retval != 0 )
> {
>     printf("ERROR:%d=%s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
> }
> ```

1. Try the `data` argument to mount with a string like `"allow_other,blksize=2048"`
2. Try using the UUID instead of device name in /etc/fstab for the NTFS partitions.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks , I need more help. I tried all you listed(expect 3, I would try later), that didn't work.

Comment: You say `ntfs-3g` is shown in `/proc/filesystems`. If you could, post what errno you get from the mount call, it would be easier to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: ntfs-3g is not in /proc/filesystems.

Comment: do u see anything like `fuse` in /proc/filesystems